# Why this app is required by your device administrator and can't be Uninstall?

Tags: android, mdm, device-admin, soti

When I am trying to uninstall my application then it's showing **"This app is required by your device administrator and can't uninstall "**. But We have not implemented any device administrator in my application and not given any permission for that.
We are using SOTI Mobile Control service for MDM.
Without MDM it's working but with MDM it's showing this error.

I am checking many links but all links showing for how to uninstall but I want to Why getting this issue?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your app. It's the way it was installed by SOTI Mobile Control.

Comment: @Henry How can i uninstall app from SOTI Mobile Control? Other apps can be install and uninstall without any administrator rights.

Comment: @JigarShekh Is your device is rooted or SOTI is signed with system signature/Its a system app?